# error uploading images using paperclip (local server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am getting an error when trying to upload images to my (listings) using the paperclip gem. The error that the browser outputs is: 1 error prohibited this listing from being saved: Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be **As a note, image magic has been successfully installed on my computer and there are no issues there

my listing.rb file

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

my gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
```

my listings_controller

```
 def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
    end
end
```

and finally my form

```
<%= form_for @listing, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to include [`file`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file) on your system.

If you're using Windows, you need to download file from [this URL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm), install it on your hard drive and then add it to your PATH environment var:

> 1. Click "Start"
> 2. On "Computer", right-click and select "Properties"
> 3. In Properties, select "Advanced System Settings"
> 4. Click the "Environment Variables" button
> 5. Locate the "PATH" var - at the end, add the path to your newly installed `file.exe` (typically `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`)
> 6. Restart any CMD shells you have open & see if it works

Comment: thanks! i tried this and when I restarted my server the app wont run now? I posted the screen shot of my command line

Comment: okay fixed that issue, here is my PATH C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\Users\Art West\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/bin   BUT still getting the same original error

Comment: Absolutely you are a life-saver

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to attach a file that is not properly recognised as an image, or one that has an image extension and has different content (like a PDF, for example).

Some workarounds are discussed here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1924

It might help to check the log file as well - it should tell you what Paperclip thinks the type of the attachment is.

Comment: hello thank you but I have tried uploading PNGs, JPGS and all normal image files without any luck!